# Can I return early (mid-function) in ClojureScript?

Tags: clojurescript

I have a function that is iterating over a moderately sized list of strings and is looking through some JSON returned from a server for the existence of a value in the data.  The code will be run many times, so I want it to be fast.  Is there any way I can return as soon as I find the value I'm looking for?

```
(defn find-type [js-data-set]
  (doseq [type all-type-strs]
    (when (aget js-data-set type)
      (return true)))) ; is there a way to do this?
```

Answer (score 4):

The built-in `some` function will find the first value matching a predicate, which fits this case rather nicely. More generally, you can use `loop` / `recur`, though that's rarely the most idiomatic option.

```
(defn find-type [js-data-set]
  (some #(goog.object/get js-data-set %) all-type-strs))
```

Comment: This solution handles that specific case, but I had actually simplified my code for simplicity, so this doesn't really answer my question.  Is there really no way to return early from a function even though doing so is a core mechanic of the language CLJS is built on?

Comment: There is no early return mechanism, despite the underlying language support for it. You can break out of a `loop` by not calling `recur`. Once you get used to a more expression oriented style, you probably won't even notice! In fact, the only times I have multiple returns in my pure JavaScript functions are for `if` blocks, which is not relevant in CLJS as `if` is an expression.